# Proving the monotone class theorem (Any circular reasoning?)

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

I tried to prove the Monotone Class Theorem. We denote $A$ to be an algebra on $X$, $M(A)$ be the monotone class generated by $A$, $\sigma(A)$ be the sigma-algebra generated by $A$. What we need to show is that $M(A)$ is an algebra.

$M(A)$ is closed under complement is not hard for me. **However, it is closed under finite union is not natural.**

My way goes as $\forall E \in M(A)$, define $F_{E} =\{K \in M(A); K \cup E \in M(A)\}$, it is not hard to check $F_{E}$ is a monotone class, and we have $\forall E \in M(A)$, $F_{E} \subset M(A)$

Now if $W \in A$, we have $F_{W} = M(A)$ (1)

Can we extend (1) to all the elements of $M(A)$, i.e. $\forall E \in M(A)$, $F_{E} = M(A)$?

The answer is 'Yes'.

We need to show $\forall E \in M(A), A \subset F_{E}$,

Proof: $\forall V \in A$, $F_{V}=M(A)$, so $E \in F_{V}$, so $E \cup V \in M(A)$, so $V \in F_{E}$.

The proof seems right to me, but I always think there is some circular reasoning. Can you help me explain whether my proof is true and why the steps involved are logically reasonable?